# How can do these animations queuing?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, queue

I have several div.(It may be one or 100).
I would like to run an animation for each div.If I use the following code snippet,All animations are down together.But I want the animation be run after the previous animation.

How can I do it?

```
<style>
div{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
.move1{
    background-color: red;
}
.move2{
    background-color: green;
}
.move3{
    background-color: blue;
}
.move4{
    background-color: green;
}
.move5{
    background-color: red;
}
.move6{
    background-color: green;
}
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn1').click(function(){
            for(var i=1;i<7;i++){
                $('.move'+i).animate({height:'75px'},5000);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="move1"></div>
<div class="move2"></div>
<div class="move3"></div>
<div class="move4"></div>
<div class="move5"></div>
<div class="move6"></div>
<button id="btn1"> go </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.First, we find a random number between 0 and 7.Then, we define a function.In function all animations runs after the end of the previous animation.

[result](http://jsfiddle.net/X3Pww/embedded/result/) of x random box moving.

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn1').click(function(){
        var num2= Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
        var num=1;
        function c_a(num,num2){
            $('.move'+num).animate({height:'25px'},1000,function(){
                num=num+1;
                if(num<num2){
                    c_a(num,num2);
                }
            });
        }           
        if(num<num2){
            c_a(num,num2);
        }
    });
});
```